# How to add loading screen when loading/redirecting to external website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I have a button/link that redirects to an external website, but
the external website takes time to load. So I want to add a loading screen so that the external page will be fully loaded before revealing it.
I don't have control over the external website, and the external website has same-origin policy in place so I can't load the external website in iFrame.
How can I achieve this using any method?

Comment: It is not possible

Comment: Maybe [Link Prefetching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ) would be helpful. Also see [HTML5 Link Prefetching by David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/html5-prefetch).

Comment: This would require you to load the external website inside some kind of a frame and hide it from the user while displaying a loading screen. After that you would have to write a script that can recognize when it's done loading and then swap the loading screen with the frame that you loaded. The problem with this is that you'd be embedding someones website on yours and it may not work properly.

Comment: Link prefetching is probably your only option in this case. There is also a prerender option that works along the same lines, but might not have as much browser support. You wouldn't be able to attach a loading screen to it though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a loading screen without access to the next site. Your best shot is to use link prefetching to minimise the load time in redirect.
More can be read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ